# SQL Server: Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working on modifying the existing SQL Server stored procedure. I added two new columns to the table and modified the stored procedure as well to select these two columns as well. Although the columns are available in the table, I keep getting this error:

> Invalid column name 'INCL_GSTAMOUNT'

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: have you executed it - do you get that error? intellisense can take some time to update?

Comment: did you recompile stored procedure ?

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Whenever this happens to me, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> which refreshes `intellisense`, close the query window (save if necessary), then start a new session which usually works quite well.

Comment: I have found the keystroke sufficient (great thanks!) - no need to close the query window

Comment: Dude, you have no idea how much of my time you saved! The keyboard shortcut along with closing/opening the query window worked for me. Thanks a lot, @Ric

Answer (score 138):

Could also happen if putting string in double quotes instead of single.

Comment: That's was the reason in my case - can you please explain the reason for this

Comment: Ugh... THANK YOU!  So dumb.  Had this problem with querying for date range with dates in double-quotes.

Comment: This solution also applies to sybase ASE

Comment: When using double quotes, it's parsed as a column name instead of a string. If that column name is not available (a string usually does not exist as a column), you'll get this error.

Comment: You can use double quotes around column names to include chars that are not normally allowed or are normally reserved key words. More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you so very much for this nugget of information, I've been on this for two very frustrating hours.

Comment: Oh dear, after 30min debugging and googling it was just the quotes usage. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 10):

If you are going to **ALTER** Table column and **immediate UPDATE** the table including the new column in the **same script**. Make sure that use `GO` command to after line of code of alter table as below.

```
ALTER TABLE Location 
ADD TransitionType SMALLINT NULL
GO   

UPDATE Location SET TransitionType =  4

ALTER TABLE Location 
    ALTER COLUMN TransitionType SMALLINT NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 8):

I came here because I was getting this error. And the reason was that I was using double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') when giving values for WHERE conditions. Writing this for the future me.

Answer (score 5):

This error may ALSO occur in encapsulated SQL statements e.g.

> DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(20) SET @tableName = 'GROC'
>
> DECLARE @updtStmt nvarchar(4000)
>
> SET @updtStmt = 'Update tbProductMaster_' +@tableName +' SET
>   department_str = ' + @tableName exec sp_executesql @updtStmt

Only to discover that there are missing quotations to encapsulate the parameter "@tableName" further like the following:

> SET @updtStmt = 'Update tbProductMaster_' +@tableName +' SET
>   department_str = ''' + @tableName + ''' '

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Intellisense is not auto refreshed and you should not fully rely on that

Answer (score 2):

I just tried.
If you execute the statement to generate your local table, the tool will accept that this column name exists.
Just mark the table generation statement in your editor window and click execute.

Comment: This solution was the only one to work for me. I tried refreshing Intellisense Local Cache, Recreating Stored Proc, Reconnect to SQL Server, nothing worked until I just ran code to create table with new column name, then change to insert worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when creating a view.

Imagine a select query that executes without issue:

```
select id
from products
```

Attempting to create a view from the same query would produce an error:

```
create view app.foobar as
select id
from products
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure foobar, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'id'.

For me it turned out to be a scoping issue; note the view is being created in a different schema. Specifying the schema of the `products` table solved the issue. Ie.. using `dbo.products` instead of just `products`.

Answer (score 1):

Following procedure helped me solve this issue but i don't know why.

1. Cut the code in question given by the lines in the message
2. Save the query (e.g. to file)
3. Paste the code to where it was before
4. Again save the query

Even if it seems to be the same query executing it did not throw this error

Comment: I had a similar problem. I think an editors window save temporary data (exp. temporary table).
Maybe these steps help somebody
1. reset editor window
2. reset data (DROP TABLE  #TempTable)
3. reset SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

There can be many things:

- First attempt, make a select of this field in its source table;
- Check the instance of the sql script window, you may be in a different instance;
- Check if your join is correct;
- Verify query ambiguity, maybe you are making a wrong table reference

After these checks, run the T-sql script again

[image: Image of the script SQL]

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar problem when running a query from the code (C#) side. The column in the table that was bringing the above error had 'default value or binding' (when I checked the table's design) already added. So I just removed the column and its corresponding value as data being inserted by the query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Blazor and forgot to use any quotations...

SqlDataAdapter da = new($"select * from table where column = {value}", con);

needed to be

SqlDataAdapter da = new($"select * from table where column = '{value}'", con);

Thanks to Harry's answer above for sending down the right train of thought.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31844013)

Comment: I upvoted when I wrote my original response. I would have replied to Harry's answer directly, but I do not have a rating of 50 to do so.

Answer (score 0):

with refresh table or close and open sql server this work

Answer (score 0):

- Refresh your tables.
- Restart the SQL server.
- Look out for the spelling mistakes in Query.

Answer (score 0):

I noted that, when executing joins, `MSSQL` will throw "Invalid Column Name" if the table you are joining on is not next to the table you are joining to. I tried specifying `table1.row1` and `table3.row3`, but was still getting the error; it did not go away until I reordered the tables in the query. Apparently, the order of the tables in the statement matters.

```
+-------------+    +-------------+    +-------------+    
| table1      |    | table2      |    | table3      |    
+-------------+    +-------------+    +-------------+    
| row1 | col1 |    | row2 | col2 |    | row3 | col3 |    
+------+------+    +------+------+    +------+------+    
| ...  | ...  |    | ...  | ...  |    | ...  | ...  |    
+------+------+    +------+------+    +------+------+
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 LEFT JOIN table3 ON row1 = row3; --throws an error
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM table2, table1 LEFT JOIN table3 ON row1 = row3; --works as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, so I'll write a new answer, re: [Nick Reed's answer regarding the ordering of the tables in the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58565235/14660801).

The `JOIN` operation has two operands. In the `ON` clause, one may only refer to columns from those operands. In Nick's first example,

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 LEFT JOIN table3 ON row1 = row3; --throws an error
```

`table2` and `table3` are the operands of the `JOIN`, but the `ON` clause refers to `row1`, defined in `table1`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, the good old quit and re-launch SQL server management studio did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was using [DbUp](https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp) to add a column to a table then in the same script an UPDATE on that column and it said "invalid column <column name>".

Breaking the two statements into separate scripts resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 on g.Id = s..flashCardGroupid
```

This line above had by accident two periods in a row which caused this error message.