# Visual Studio intellisense not working for newly added columns in database

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, edmx

I'm using SQL Server and made its connection with website in Visual Studio. Now I added three new columns in users table in database and there was error in SQL server that I solved by this link
[SQL Server: Invalid Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941514/sql-server-invalid-column-name)
and now Visual Studio intellisense is not working for new columns as well giving me error doesn't contain definition for column name. Here is picture of that error in visual studio
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3kP8.png)

1) I already closed and reopen vs but did't work.

2) Already refreshed data Connection in vs.

3) need detail about why its not getting those columns.

Comment: Are you using edmx files for entity code/definition generation?

Comment: there is a file in solution explorer named as model.edmx.diagram

Comment: Open the edmx designer and update the model from database, validate and build.

Comment: I also experience similar problems on SSMS too

Comment: thanks a lot bro it worked how may I mark it as solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open your edmx file by double clicking it from solution explorer. Right click in empty area of the edmx designer window as shown in the snapshot below. Go to `Update Model From Database` context menu option:

[image]

Now go to refresh tab and update the table in which  you have added new columns as shown in the snapshot below. Entity framework will automatically pull the new columns as public properties of `user` class:

[image]