# Tag name is not right

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dataexplorer

Trying to learn SQL queries, I practice on the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

I try this query:

```
Select *
FROM Tags
WHERE TagName = "scala"
```

but have this error:

```
Invalid column name 'scala'
```

Any suggestion what is it going wrong?

Comment: Use single quotes, e.g. `'scala'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Invalid Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941514/sql-server-invalid-column-name)

Comment: In particular, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22240860.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use single quotes ('') instead of double quotes ("") for string constants ?

Comment: If you are unsure, then why did you answer? :P

Answer (score 0):

Tags must be a table of columns. Table which contain column TagName. And you are trying to find a record with 'scala' value in TagName column. But this column doesn't exist.
That all about the process. Now if you want some more help give us a context (examples).