# SQL Server query with Case with multiple whens

Tags: mysql, sql, case, where-clause

I am trying to write a sql select like below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN table1.col1 IS NOT NULL 
AND  table2.col1='someValue' THEN 'YES'
WHEN main.col2 IS NOT NULL 
AND table2.col1 NOT LIKE '%Rejected%' THEN 'YES'
        ELSE NULL END AS eligible,table1.col13,table2.col14 
        FROM table1 
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col5=table2.col6     
        WHERE eligible='YES'
```

but getting Invalid column name 'eligible', please advice

Comment: Welcome to the community. Do you have a column in either table1 or table2 named 'eligible'? If so, please post a minimally reproduceable sample of your data.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: kindly check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18941677/11236563), seems to be your  same  issue

Answer (score 0):

What you probably looking for is not `WHERE eligible`. Instead it's `HAVING eligible`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN table1.col1 IS NOT NULL AND  table2.col1='someValue'  
                THEN 'YES'
            WHEN main.col2 IS NOT NULL AND table2.col1 NOT LIKE '%Rejected%' 
                THEN 'YES'
           ELSE NULL END AS eligible,
      table1.col13,
      table2.col14 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col5=table2.col6     
HAVING eligible='YES';  /*here*/
```

Since the column `eligible` is actually an alias of your `CASE` expression and is not from any of your tables then you can't use it in `WHERE`.

If you're more familiar with using `WHERE`, here's a workaround by making the base query as subquery first:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
( SELECT CASE WHEN table1.col1 IS NOT NULL AND  table2.col1='someValue'  
                THEN 'YES'
            WHEN main.col2 IS NOT NULL AND table2.col1 NOT LIKE '%Rejected%' 
                THEN 'YES'
           ELSE NULL END AS eligible,
      table1.col13,
      table2.col14 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col5=table2.col6 ) AS subquery
WHERE eligible='YES';
```

Comment: I dont have right to upvote your answer but it answered my question suggesting two ways of having and where in right way. Thank you again

Comment: If it solve your issue, you can mark as answer. That way others who might have same issue will know that this is a possible solution for them. Refer this link ["What should I do when someone answer my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)